# MongoDB and PHP field with same name can be added?

Tags: php, mongodb, push

I have a problem and i couldn't figure it out alone so I'm here because i really need some help D

I need to know if i can add a field with the same name, like, id, and id but with a diferente value

$usedWord = array('word' => $word);

```
//  search for the word based on the array
$found = $collection->findOne($usedWord); 

// If it returns 
if (empty($found)) { // Here, it'll insert

    $info = array('word'=> $word, 
                  'id' => $id, 
                  'path' => $path,
                  'start' => $startOfTheWord, 
                  'end' => $endOfTheWord);
} else { 

} 

$collection->insert($info);

//disc from servidor
$conn->close();
```

On the Else part, i tried codes to add a new 'id', path and so on, the question is, can i create another 'id', 'patch' and so on OR i should create 'id1', path1 and so on ?

OBs:. i used $push and couldn't make it work =\

Comment: It isn't very clear what you're asking.  Are you trying to change the value of an existing document or add a new document with the values in your array?

Comment: Can you show how you tried to use push? It should work

Comment: I have the field word, right? i used the if to see if the word i've sent by a form exist, if it don't, I'll save the data, if the word already exists then i just need to add another id, path, start and end.

I have id, i wished to the mongo to create another id with a different number, like the first id the mongo saved was 12 and the new one would be 22. so there should be the first id: "12"  and the second id:22

Comment: Heres the code that i tried to do inside else

$filter = array('word'=>$found);

            $info = array(
                'id' => $id, 'path' => $path,
                'start' => $startWord, 'end' => $endWord);
                
            $update = array(
                '$push'=>array('id' => $id, 'path' => $path,
                'start' => $startWord, 'end' => $endWord));
            
            $usedWord->update($filter,$update);
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I got your question, but if you are sking about duplicate fields here what mongo docs says:

> BSON documents may have more than one field with the same name. Most
>   [MongoDB interfaces](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/drivers/), however, represent MongoDB with a structure (e.g.
>   a hash table) that does not support duplicate field names. If you need
>   to manipulate documents that have more than one field with the same
>   name, see the driver [documentation for your driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/drivers/).

Anyway I think you should avoid duplicate fields in your documents it looks like there's something wrong with document structure design.

Comment: So..even if I'll only use it do save the same kind of data, it's not worthy, is it? what should i do? x.x Any advices ? i must use duplicate fields =\

Comment: I don't think you really must use duplicates fields, there's always a way to redesign you document structure and use either embeded array or a new collection which is then referenced from your main one.

Comment: I'm having another problem now, i have this:

db.comida.insert(
 { _id:1,
  "pratos":[
  {comida:"Lasanha", preco:20.00},
  {comida:"Panqueca", preco:15.00}
  ]
 }
)

And i'm trying to update preco: 20.00

but i can't see to update it, i'm using this code

db.comida.update(
 {_id: 4, "pratos.comida": "Lasanha"}, {$set: {"prato.$.preco": 12.99}}

)

Comment: @MaksymStrukov : I happened to have this issue today, was surprised when robo3T said 'valid json' & inserted the document to DB, Seems like robo3T meant  'valid BSON' rather than 'valid json' - Also this doesn't seem to happen from code is because of driver&language restrictions !! Thanks for this..